# Looking for vampire-themed short story in 1960's sci-fi anthology

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, vampire

Library book, remembered as Orbit series, but it could have been Dangerous Visions or New Dimensions or even Year's Best SF.  This was mid-60's, 1965-69, and the book was fairly new, possibly paperback.  The story was about vampires, whom I believe were brother and sister, living in a Victorian mansion in San Francisco, where I moved shortly thereafter.  (I don't believe there were any straight horror anthologies then, thus its inclusion in a sci-fi anthology; maybe they were alien vampires.)

No recollection as to the author, although I had read a lot of sci-fi and horror by then.  Wish I could remember more details.  I just remember its being a really good, atmospheric story that would probably make more sense to me now after living in SF for so many years.  I would love to read it again.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you remember anything about the other stories in the anthology?

Comment: [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org) doesn't have any Orbit anthologies published in the 1960s. The earliest one is in 1974, but is horror,  "The Ghouls."

Comment: Thanks for the ISFDB reference.  Can't believe I didn't know about it.  Orbit was first published in 1966 and I know for sure I read some of them in my home state in the 60's.  But it could have been as late as 1970, since that is when I moved to California.

Comment: No, I don't remember any of the other stories in that volume.  I simply cannot tell by looking at the table of contents for each Orbit anthology whether one of them is "the" story.